# Runtime Error(NZEC) on CodeChef

Tags: python-3.x, runtime-error

Here is the Question: https://www.codechef.com/problems/BUY1GET1

When I submit I am getting a Runtime Error(NZEC) on CodeChef.

```
t=int(input())
while(t):
    n=input()
    #n=list(n)
    a=[0]*53
    cost=0
    for i in n:
        if(ord(i)>=65 and ord(i)<=90):
            x=ord(i)-64
            a[x]=a[x]+1
        else:
            x=ord(i)-70
            a[x]=a[x]+1
    #print(a)
    for i in range(1,53):
        if(a[i]>0):
            cost=cost+(a[i]//2+a[i]%2)
    print(cost)
    t=t-1
```

Its running correctly on my Python Shell.
What is the problem? Please Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the `else` block.
Are you absolutely sure that `ord(i)` is between `70` and `(70+53-1)`??
Try writing `elif ord(i) >=70 and ord(i) < 123` instead of `else` and see if the problem persists.